# Comparing the two set of data from columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the data say for example

```
A1= 1     B1= 1    C1 result  " "
    3         5                3
    5         9
    6                          6
    8                          8
    9   
    12                        12
```

Condition is "not-shared" with "B" column should be in corresponding raw of "A"column

Answer (score 2):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0,A1,"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]